# Echo out information sent via html Select with PHP

Tags: php, html, select, echo

I have 3 select boxes, one for day, month and year.

Once the user chooses their desired day, month and year they click 'send'.

When they click send I want PHP to echo out their selection.

The code I have so far is:

```
<?php
$day = array(range(1,31));
$month = array(range(1,12));
$year = array(range(2011,2020));
?>
Day:
<select>
  <?php foreach($day[0]++ as $key => $value) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key ?>"><?php echo $value ?></option>
  <?php }?>
</select>
<br>
Month:
<select>
  <?php foreach($month[0]++ as $key => $value) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key ?>"><?php echo $value ?></option>
  <?php }?>
</select>
<br>
Year:
<select>
  <?php foreach($year[0]++ as $key => $value) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key ?>"><?php echo $value ?></option>
  <?php }?>
</select>
<input type='submit' value='Send' name='poll' />

Date Selected:
```

Any suggestions, improvements , links code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does /doesn't work so far?

Comment: This is all the code I have so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing can't be done with **PHP** alone. You need to use client side scripting to know how the user is interacting with the **DOM**. There are many different ways that you could accomplish this. Your best bet is to use an **AJAX** framework like **jQuery** (as mentioned above), **Prototype**, **Dojo**, or **YUI**. I'd probably go with jQuery, because it's very easy to pick up if you're used to css selectors.

First off you'd change your html a little, providing **ID** or **Class name** for the input element. And, also adding a display element, in this case a **DIV**. Then you could select those DOM nodes like this:

```
     <script>
        $( document ).ready( function () {
            $( '#send' ).click( function () {

                var span = document.createElement( 'span' );
                $( span ).attr( 'id', 'options' );

                $( 'select' ).each( function () {
                    $( span ).append($( this ).val() + " ");
                });                 

                $( '#show' ).html( span );

            });
        });
    </script>
```

I mocked up a quick Fiddle this: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6St27/)

Answer (score 1):

Use a comprehensive datepicker instead, like the [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) built into [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/).  They have examples on-site.

If you go down the 3 dropdown selection route, you'll either need to have some funky dynamic switching in there, or be prepared for invalid dates.  31st of February anyone? :)

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to specify  tags, and specify where you want the data to go. Second, you need to name your input fields to you can retrieve them.

You might want to take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Answer (score 0):

Where does the form post?  Where is the code that attempts to echo the values?  What you have here is the select elements with their options being generated when the page is rendered, but where's the next step?

Hint: Your `select` elements will need names in order to access those values at any time.  Also, if *all* you want to do is show the user the values that were selected, you don't need to post the form anywhere or do this on the server-side.  JavaScript can do the job just fine :)